# "Unknown column 'insertcounter' in 'where clause'" при выполнении UPDATE

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте.

В общем, я поругался с логикой и столкнулся с ошибкой, которая в заголовке вопроса.

Сам SQL-запрос:

```
UPDATE `static` SET `value` = `value` + 1 where `name` = insertcounter
```

В общем, погуглив, понял, что ошибка говорит, мол, не найден столбец `insertcounter`, но ведь ясно сказано, что `insertcounter` - это значение в столбце `name`.

В общем, муть какая-то.

Как будет корректнее составить такой запрос, который будет обновлять значение записи с `name` = `insertcounter`, увеличивая значение на 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так может в кавычки строки нужно брать? В самые обыкновенные?

```
UPDATE `static` SET `value` = `value` + 1 where `name` = 'insertcounter'
```

Comment: @KoVadim Там суть в следующем: 
Один запрос выполняется для нескольких десятков строк в таблице. 
Для поля `name` параметр для сравнения заносится в переменную `$i_name`

А сам запрос имеет вид:

`$db->query("UPDATE `static` SET `value` = `value` + 1 WHERE `name` = $i_name");`